# invalid regular expression flag n

Tags: php, kohana-3

I am trying to get parameters from url in kohana 3 using the following code but fire bug is given me an error message "invalid regular expression flag n"
the code is:

### CONTROLLER

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Test extends Controller_Template
{
public function action_index()
{
    $this->template = View::factory('par');
    $this->template->content = View::factory('par');
}
public function get()
{
    $param1 = $this->request->param('param1');
    $param2 = $this->request->param('param2');
    $param3 = $this->request->param('param3');

    echo "This is param1: ".$param1; 
    echo "This is param2: ".$param2; 
    echo "This is param3: ".$param3;
}
}
```

### VIEW

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org   /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>


<?php $x=1;
  $y=2;
  $z=3;
?>

<input type="button" value = "button" onClick=<?php echo url::site('test/get'.$x);?> />
</body>
</html>
```

### BOOT STRAP

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<param1>)(/<param2>)(/<param3>)))',
array(
    'param1' => '\d+',
    'param2' => '\d+',
    'param3' => '\d+',
))
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'test',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

please help me resolve this.

Comment: nothing is displayed in the browser.... just the following line is displayed in firebug:                                               invalid regular expression flag n                               [Break On This Error] /param/index.php/test/get1                  also i am trying to get all the three parameters ...please tell me how to do that

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the browser sees something like this:

```
onClick=/param/index.php
```

The `onClick` attribute is being interpreted as JavaScript and `/param/index.php` in JavaScript is trying to be a regular expression literal followed by a property access. The regex will be `/param/` with modifiers `i`, `n`, `d`, `e`, and `x`. The `i` means case insensitive matching so that gets through; then you an error because there is no `n` modifier for a JavaScript regular expression.

I think you're trying to make the button act like a link so you need to add some quotes and an assignment to `window.location`:

```
<input type="button" value = "button" onClick="window.location = '<?php echo url::site('test/get'.$x);?>'" />
```

That should get you closer to where you're trying to go or at least get you past the mysterious "invalid regular expression flag n" error.

Comment: thanks a lot ... this resolved my problem and also getting three parameters.